# the actual no. of diameter of stranded conductor

Tags: conductors

I have ordered a .G.C. CU. COND. 3 CORE XLPE/SWA/PVC 50mm² 11K.V. ( no.of diameter of wire before stranding 7/3.02) but unfortunately I received (no. of diameter of wire after stranding 7/2.754) after negotiating with the supplier they said this is the size of wires after stranding.
is this correct???

Comment: Does the supplier have any public specifications of the wire? Do they mention what tolerance the values should be in? Do they mention they make them by some sort of standard dictating these specifications? If you don't know what the specs are, how can you know if it's something within the specified values or not?

Answer (score 0):

A 3.02 mm diameter wire has a cross-sectional area of 7.16 mm<sup>2</sup>. 7 strands will have a total CSA = 50.1 mm<sup>2</sup>.

A 2.754 mm diameter wire has a cross-sectional area of 5.957 mm<sup>2</sup>. 7 strands will have a total CSA = 41.7 mm<sup>2</sup>.

It seems to me that you are correct and they are not.